# Two arrays from seperate objects, one common Id. How to merge them into a wrapper class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class

So for this is what i have and i have zero clue on how to continue. What i do know is the Product2 Id is what links to the arrays together, to end up displaying like so....and i have no idea exactly how to do that...I know both lists will have the same Product2 Id but beyond that i'm at a loss.

[image]

```
public class wrapperClass
{
    public integer price {get;set;}
    public integer quantity {get;set;}
    public Id productId {get;set;}
    public Id pbEntry {get;set;}
    public Id themeConversionId {get; set;}
    public Id parentOpp {get;set;}
    
    public wrapperClass(Theme_Conversion__c tc) {
        this.themeConversionId = tc.Id;
        this.price = tc.Min_or_Flat_Fee_Amount__c;
        this.quantity = tc.Quantity__c;
        this.productId = tc.To_Theme__r.Id;
        this.themeConversionId = tc.Id;
        this.parentOpp = tc.Sales_Toolkit__r.Opportunity_Name__r.Id;
    }
    public wrappperClass(PricebookEntry pbe){
        this.pbEntry = pbe.Id;
        this.productId= pbe.Product2Id;
    }
}

@AuraEnabled
public static boolean getParentOpp(string recordId){
    Theme_Conversion__c[] qli = getLineItems(recordId);
    PricebookEntry[] pbe = getPriceBookEntry(qli);
}

/**
 * retrieves line items 
 * @param recordId
 */
public static List<Theme_Conversion__c> getLineItems(string recordId){
    return  [ SELECT Id,Min_or_Flat_Fee_Amount__c,Quantity__c, Product2__r.Id, Sales_Toolkit__r.Opportunity_Name__r.Id 
              FROM Theme_Conversions__c 
              WHERE Sales_Toolkit__c =:recordId];
}

/**
 * retrives pricebookentries for related products
 * @param qli
 */
public static List<PricebookEntry> getPriceBookEntry(Theme_Conversion[] qli){
    Set<string> productIds = new Set<string>();
    
    for(Product2 p : qli){
        productIds.add(p.Product2__r.Id);
    }
    return [SELECT Id, Product2Id 
            FROM PricebookEntry 
            WHERE Product2Id =:productIds AND Pricebook2Id =:PRICEBOOK2_ID];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared

```
public Product2 product {get;set;}
public PricebookEntry pbEntry {get;set;}
public Theme_Conversion__c themeConversionId {get; set;}
public Opportunity parentOpp {get;set;}
```

But you're assinging an `Id` to those properties, so you should change their type:

```
public Id product {get;set;}
public Id pbEntry {get;set;}
public Id themeConversionId {get; set;}
public Id parentOpp {get;set;}
```

Even the signature of `getPriceBookEntry` is wrong: it returns a list of `PricebookEntry`, not a `String`, so It should be:
`public static List<PricebookEntry> getPriceBookEntry(Theme_Conversion[] qli) {`

---

In order to merge the two lists you need a Map. The key will be the common property, the Product2's Id, and the value will be a wrapper class instance.
After retrieving the list of `Theme_Conversion__c` you can populate the map, then you can retrieve the list of `PricebookEntry`, loop over it and retrive the wrapper class from the map using `Product2Id` in order to set the missing field.
It is guaranteed that the key exists in the map, since you retrieved the PBE using the map's keySet.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static boolean getParentOpp(string recordId){
    Map<Id, WrapperClass> mapProductIdToWrapper = new Map<Id, WrapperClass>();
    Theme_Conversion__c[] qliList = getLineItems(recordId);
    for (Theme_Conversion__c qli : qliList) {
        WrapperClass wrapper = new WrapperClass(qli);
        mapProductIdToWrapper.put(wrapper.product, wrapper);
    }
    PricebookEntry[] pbeList = getPriceBookEntry(qliList);
    for (PricebookEntry pbe : pbeList) {
        mapProductIdToWrapper.get(pbe.Product2Id).pbEntry = pbe.Id;
    }
}
```

If `getPriceBookEntry` method is used only in this class, you can change its signature to
`private static List<PricebookEntry> getPriceBookEntry(Set<Id> productIds) {`
then update its body accordingly. This way you can call it passing `mapProductIdToWrapper.keySet()`